# RPI desktop windows do not stretch over full resolution

Tags: vnc

I have a strange problem, cannot get a start menu to touch the bottom taskbar (on upside taskbar it is touching...) Somehow RPI OS thinks the taskbar is higher than it is in reality.
It is also affecting other windows, like when i put chrome to full screen, it only pops up to what it thinks is viewable area (on picture the file manager is put to full screen - see the square next to X that is closing the window)

This is viewed through VNC...

1. i set the full HD res in raspi-config,
2. tried to set resolution in start > preferences > screen configuration (no options!)
3. in config.txt there is no forced resolution set, only forced hdmi hotplug and hdmi safe mode (both do not affect it...)

i noticed this a while ago but ignored it thinking it was bug that will be soon fixed however it is few months now and its starting to pi**ing me off..

[image]

Comment: This question lacks any meaningful data or diagnostics. You have NOT said what OS or what YOU ACTUALLY did. The illegible picture doesn't help. Guessing OS  [What are the pros and cons of the new Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135702/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-new-raspberry-pi-os-bullseye) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/135666/8697

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the pros and cons of the new Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135702/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-new-raspberry-pi-os-bullseye)

Comment: Hi @Dougie, not really, did not help sorry. <br> The thing is  - as shown on picture, the file manager window is not stretched fully to size of desktop. only to lest say one third of it. If i want window to be on full size, i have to resize it manually. it does not do it by itself hitting the up arrow in the top right corner on window. (down arrow minimizes it, upo maximizes and X closes it.)

Comment: @Milliways - the OS is Raspberry Bullseye 64 bit full with latest updates, 4gig ram, running from 64GB USB3 stick.  Cpu overclock is 2147MHz, and supply voltage is 5.15V, and is using I2C. VRAM is 128MB and Swap is turned off... Also, other hardware info is on posted picture.